# Get user's GUID via IAdsUser

Tags: delphi, com, active-directory

For some reason, the GUID returned by IAdsUser.GUID is the same no matter what userobject i inspect. I have also tried using the IAdsUser.get('objectGUID') - but that fails. Does anyone have a working piece of delphi code to get the unique identifier for an AD user?
Getting the SID is no problem.

```
mAddr:='WinNT://' + dom1 + '/' + uid1;

if length(Password)>0 then
mRes:=ADsOpenObject(PChar(mAddr),Username,Password,1,IADsUser,usr) else
mRes:=ADsGetObject(PChar(mAddr), IADsUser, usr);

if (mRes=S_OK) and (usr<>NIL) then
Begin
  ADSIUser.UID:=UserName;
  ADSIUser.FullName:=usr.FullName;
  ADSIUser.Disabled:=usr.AccountDisabled;
  ADSIUser.LockedOut:=usr.IsAccountLocked;
  ADSIUser.GUID:=usr.GUID; //<--- returns the same for ALL users
```

Comment: Are the other usr properties valid?

Comment: I think this only works with the Ldap provider

Comment: Yes, all the info is valid for the other fields.
I can enumerate the users, but when i try to dump out username and guid, all the users have the same GUID. Which doesnt make sense (i suspect it can return the classid for the com object, in which case its the delphi typelib import function which has an error).
I have tried this both local on my machine (which lists the profiles on my machine only) and on a large network with 4000+ users. Getting the SID etc. is no problem, but it refuses to give the unique user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't get the objectGUID via the WinNT:// provider.  If you can't use the LDAP:// provider, can you use [IADsNameTranslate](http://www.rlmueller.net/NameTranslateFAQ.htm#How%20do%20I%20convert%20an%20NT%20Name%20to%20a%20GUID)?

Comment: This worked under citrix:

    mObj:=CreateOleObject('NameTranslate');
    if not varIsNull(mObj) then
    Begin
      try
        mObj.Init(ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC,'');
        mObj.Set(ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4, mDomain + '\' + mUser);
        mData:=WideString(mObj.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_GUID));
        showmessage(mData);
      finally
        mObj:=null;
      end;
    end;

Comment: I accept this as a solution. Getting the GUID is only something we do when our system is setup to use AD, meaning that your hint covers what we need for now. Thank you for your help!